# 6 chips numbered 1-6. E= 2 even number chips are picked. F=2 odd-numbered chips are picked.

Tags: probability

Are E and F mutually exclusive?
Yes, since P(E intersection F)=0

Are E and F independent?
No, since P(E/F)=0 and not equal to P(E)

Is tihs solution correct?

Comment: Picked with replacement (one at a time) or without replacement?

Comment: It is not stated.

Comment: The solution is correct in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is totally correct.